# I am tracking my investments - If column 2 (contains my contribution) is less than column 3 (investment return), return column 1 (date of occurrence)

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, accounting

I have a spreadsheet on Google Sheets that tracks my investment. Based on average returns I have calculated the average return rate over the years.

First column no.1 has a list of dates. Column no.2 has my contribution. Column no.3 has the average return.

I would like to do the following if statement: `if(column2<column3)return(column1)`

This is so I can see the date my returns become more than my contributions.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This code  assumes  that column1 is A, column2 is B and column3 is C.
the formula for the IF statement is:
first the thing you want to test
next the return value if true
last the return value if false.
I have set false to return 0, but you might want something else.

```
=IF($B1<$C1;$A1;0)
```